# Parsing of strings containing forward slash in node.js command line

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi I am writing a node js app where I need to pass the path to some file via command line. I need to do this for configuration purposes. I understand that I can put all config details in a json file and then load it inside the app. But this is a specific requirement.

Here is my code

app.js

```
  ----
  -----
  console.log(process.argv); 
  ---
  --
 // Start server
```

Now when I run this file in node as:

```
 node app.js hii
```

Output

```
 'hii'
```

But if I do

```
node app.js '/samplePath'
```

I get this output in DOS:

```
'\'/samplePath\''
```

I get this output in Git Bash:

```
'C:/Program Files/Git/samplePath'
```

How will I get just '/samplePath' as output? What am I doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try using double quotes for the parameter

Comment: No luck. It is still the same output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get the last item, try

```
 process.argv[2].split(/\//).pop();
```

You will have to parse the command line options your self.  However you can look into this node module that will make this easy for you.

```
npm install commander
```

Here is an example from their Github page

```
var program = require('commander');

program
  .version('0.0.1')
  .option('-p, --peppers', 'Add peppers')
  .option('-P, --pineapple', 'Add pineapple')
  .option('-b, --bbq', 'Add bbq sauce')
  .option('-c, --cheese [type]', 'Add the specified type of cheese [marble]', 'marble')
  .parse(process.argv);
```

Comment: Thanks Nathan, I tried using commander. I was not successful. How do I add the parsing logic to accept the forward slash?